# using elasticsearch with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

Been looking into creating a faceted search with elasticsearch

my data will be in mongodb

quite new to this but am i right in assuming and handle the normal queries with the database that pull back results but  use data returned(in JSON)with elasticsearch for the faceted queries. sorry if it sounds a weird question cant get my head round it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch requires you to index the data in your database into Elasticsearch. This allows Elasticsearch to build an [inverted index](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index&ei=rWdGU5DKNozjOb3HgcAP&usg=AFQjCNHTJUA8IMeMdzyXnJnJ6RZx8qV2JA&sig2=U5K0CYmx0wjoNv18dHgvfg&bvm=bv.64507335,d.ZWU) of all your data and thus making it searchable.

Essentially what you will end up with is a duplication of your data in Elasticsearch, however in a different form. To index this data a plugin has been developed to create a river from MongoDB to Elasticsearch located [here](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb).

Once you have started Elasticsearch, it exposes an end point where you can send queries in the form of Elasticsearch' [Query DSL](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) language. There you can perform facets on your data, like so -

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
     "match_all": {}
   },
   "facets": {
     "tag": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "name",
         "size": 6
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Any more questions I can clarify these for you.

Comment: thanks nate you've been most helpful will take a look at the plugin you suggested